# regexp_substr equivalent in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this code in oracle PLSQL:

```
select * from con_transaccioncabecera c
where c.cab_estadocon in
(select regexp_substr('S-C-I-A','[^-]+',1,level) from dual
connect by regexp_substr('S-C-I-A','[^-]+',1,level) is not NULL)
```

I typed the string 'S-C-I-A', but actually, there would go a variable.

I need an equivalent in plpgsql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much easier in Postgres (no PL/pgSQL required)

```
select * 
from con_transaccioncabecera c
where c.cab_estadocon = any (string_to_array('S-C-I-A','-'))
```